# PHP no result being returned

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a script that as far as I can tell should be working, but it isn't and I'm trying to find out what I'm doing wrong!

```
echo $result = "select email from jb_jbe_it_collated;";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $email = $row['email'];
    echo $email;
  }
```

All the page shows is

```
select email from jb_jbe_it_collated;
```

And not the result that I'd be expecting

There is an include page with the following connection string

```
$con = mysqli_connect("1.1.1.1","user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
mysqli_select_db("webjobs", $con);
```

I'm not getting an error message and I can connect directly to the database with those credentials and run the query, so am unsure what's going wrong!  Any ideas?

Comment: did u run the query against ur db(`mysqli_query`)?

Comment: Either you do `echo $email;`after assigning the value to it, or  `echo $row['email'];`Also remove the echo out of the line `echo $result = "select email from jb_jbe_it_collated;";` and change it to `$result = "select email from jb_jbe_it_collated";`

Comment: `echo $email = $row['email'];` is valid. It will both assign and echo.

Comment: You haven't run your query that is in $result.

Answer (score 6):

You are not running the query.

`mysqli_fetch_array` takes a result object not a string. You have to run `mysqli_query` first to get a result object:

```
$query = "select email from jb_jbe_it_collated;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $email = $row['email'];
    echo $email;
  }
```

Examples are given in the [mysqli_fetch_array docs](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: $query = "select email from jb_jbe_it_collated;";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $email = $row['email'];
   echo $email;
  }
 
 like that?

Comment: @franglais My example was using the object orientated style. I've changed the example to match your question more closely.

Comment: Thanks - I knew it was going to be something really stupid, but you know when you are looking at something for ages and you just can't work out what the hell is going wrong...!

Comment: @franglais I know that feeling! The mysqli docs are very useful when troubleshooting these types of issues though as most pages have good examples of use.

Answer (score 0):

Use CLI (command line interface).

```
$ mysql -u {username} -p {database_name}
```

Enter user/password and write your query

```
mysql> select email from jb_jbe_it_collated;
```

In PHP you can check MySQL's last error with function [`mysql_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php).